# Getting Error while converting docx int PDF POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xdocreport

Hi i am trying to convert docx file into pdf. but getting below error. I have done lots of googling but not getting proper solution.
I have added following jars

- poi-scratchpad-3.16.jar
- poi-3.16.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.16.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar
- poi-examples-3.16.jar
- poi-excelant-3.16.jar
- fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-2.0.0.jar
- fr.opensagres.xdocreport.samples.docxandvelocity.converters-0.9.0-sources.jar
- itext-2.1.7.jar

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.getBodyElements(Lorg/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter;)Ljava/util/List;
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitHeader(PdfMapper.java:182)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitHeader(PdfMapper.java:111)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitHeaderRef(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:1083)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.visitHeadersFooters(MasterPageManager.java:197)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.addSection(MasterPageManager.java:166)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.compute(MasterPageManager.java:113)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.initialize(MasterPageManager.java:83)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitBodyElements(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:219)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.start(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:186)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:56)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38)
      at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45)
      at com.eko.app.agreement.business.service.EsignTest.main(EsignTest.java:36)
  ```

Below is my Java Code

```
public class EsignTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(new File("/home/optimus/Desktop/ee.docx")));

    for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        if (runs != null) {
            for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                String text = r.getText(0);
                System.out.println("Row : "+text);
                if (text != null && text. contains("«Company_Name»")) {
                    text = text.replace("«Company_Name»", "Rohit Communication");
                    r.setText(text, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(doc, new FileOutputStream("/home/optimus/Desktop/output.pdf"), null);
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible jars in your classpath

Comment: Check your imports, `org.apache.poi` is no longer part of the xdocreport namespace.

Comment: Ya it is resolved now, actually this function get removed from poi-ooxml-3.16.jar, and same is available in poi-ooxml-3.15.jar

Comment: Interesting, `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter` has never been a package in Apache POI. I am now wondering where you got your jars. But as long as it is resolved. Notice that in the past year we discovered that `xdocreport` was using the `org.apache.poi` namespace. They are no longer doing that, so if you are writing new stuff, it would be best to use all the latest jars, or you will find it harder to upgrade in the future.

Comment: For namespace, see https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues/174